# Sort fetch request based on relationship attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

Let's say I have two entities; `Item` and `LocalizableString`. The `LocalizableString`  entity has two attributes; `string` and `locale`. The `Item` entity has a to-many relationship to `LocalizableString` called `localizedTitles`. Where there's one string entity per "locale".

Now, in my app, I have some context/setting that determines what `locale` I want to use when showing the UI. So let's say I have a `UITableViewController` with an `NSFetchedResultsController` handling the data flow.

My question is: can I sort the `Item` entities based on the `LocalizableString`'s `string` property where `locale` is for example `en`? And can I do this in the *fetch request*, not after having fetched all items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that, but you do not have to fetch any particular locale upfront. Your fetched results controller would just fetch the `Item` objects, and you can then refer to the correct string as you need it.

One way to implement this is to add a convenience function to the `Item` class, something like the following

```
func titleWithLocale(identifier: String) -> String? {
   if let title = self.localizedTitles.filter 
         { $0.locale == identifier }
         .first as? LocalizableString {
     return title.string
   }
   return nil
}
```

Most likely you will have to tweak this code to conform to the strict typing of Swift, but you get the idea.

If you need to sort by the title string, perhaps you need a different approach. If you know that each `Item` has a localized title in the respective locale you can fetch the `LocalizedTitle` entity with a predicate the filters for the locale:

```
 request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "locale = %@", "en")
```

Obviously, you can sort by `string` with the usual sort descriptors. Now, to populate your table, you get to the item by following the relationshp in the other direction.

```
 let title = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
 let item = title.item
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear in my question. But I need to be able to _sort_ on the LocalizableString.

Comment: OK, I have expanded my answer.

Comment: That is actually what I just ended up doing! My main fetch request is for the  `LocalizableString` entity where the inverse relationship for my `Item`'s title is not nil. I'm gonna update my question!

Comment: So you should accept this answer. You can use this fetch request in the fetched results controller. The query will not return and titles if they are nil, i.e., non-existing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a fetch request for my `LocalizableString` entity instead. With a predicate that checks the `locale` and the inverse relationship:

`NSPredicate(format: "locale == %@ AND itemName != nil", locale)`